# Promise resolve used as a function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ecmascript-6, promise

I have been working with Promises in Javascript lately but I have difficulty trying to understand what exactly happens here.

A Google Maps script url is being set with a callback of `initMap`. So when Google Maps finishes loading this callback will fire.

In turn it calls `resolveFunc()`. `resolvefunc()` is set within the promise but I don't get this part:

```
resolveFunc = resolve;
```

What is the use of setting it equal to the resolve function?

```
<script>
  var resolveFunc = null;
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolveFunc = resolve;
  });
  promise.then(function() {
    console.log('loaded');
  });
  function initMap() {
    resolveFunc();
  }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Maybe better to understand: `var promise = new Promise(resolve => { window.initMap = resolve; })`

Comment: Do you understand how JSONP works?

Comment: Yes I understand what happens now after reviewing this all and with the help of comments here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can see for this construction is that you want to be able to access a Promise that resolves when the google maps api is loaded.

1. A new promise object is created.
2. The resolve function of that promise is assigned out of scope in to a window variable `resolveFunc`
3. A `.then` is assigned to the promise that issues a console log when the promise resolves.
4. The assigned resolve function is called when the initMap function is run by the external gmaps script.
5. The `console.log` inside the `.then` will fire.

I can't see any need for this that running code inside the initMap without the promise construction could also achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this construction before.

I can only think of one reason for it: to allow some sort of modularization.  The loading of the Google Maps URL will trigger the resolution of that promise.  In the meantime, other modules may have attached themselves with `.then` to this promise, to be run when this script has been loaded.

That global `promise` variable is really ugly, but it would serve for this purpose.

**Note**: I mean 'module' in its generic sense: some reasonably independent, cohesive chunk of code.

Comment: Oh now I see, it is assigned to the resolve function but it is not yet executed until `resolveFunc()` is called because this actually refers to the `resolve` function.

Comment: Right.  Bergi's comment show what looks to be a better way to achieve the same end.  But the main point is that this promise is resolved from the JSONP callback.  And if I'm right, the reason for that is to expose this promise to additional callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this pattern is that the script, that is loaded with:

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
```

..., should be able to resolve the promise. For that the script needs to call the `resolve` function that the promise constructor provides. But since `resolve` is local to that constructor, the authors have used a solution where they assign that function to a *global* variable, which *will* be available to the loaded script.

That script will certainly look at the `callback` argument present in the url, and extract the value following it. It will be assigned to some variable, let's say `callback`, and then they will trigger the resolution with:

```
window[callback]();
```

which will be synonym for `resolveFunc`, which in turn is synonym for `resolve`.

That script could not have done that with a call to `resolve`:

```
resolve();
```

... as that would be an unknown variable.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is known as Deferred pattern which was notably [implemented in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). It is prone to be [antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) but is possibly justified here because it's a reasonable way to move from Google Maps API callback to a promise.

`promise` resolution is deferred until `resolveFunc` callback is called. `promise` is global and can be used inside the application. In case it's not used, this can be considered antipattern for the reasons mentioned above:

> It is easy to fall into this when you don't really understand promises and think of them as glorified event emitters or callback utility.

It could be just:

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    console.log('loaded');
  }
</script>
```